# Add data to Django database through views or JSON dictionary

Tags: python, json, django, model

The simplest of my tables is as follows:

```
class Player(models.Model):
number = models.CharField(max_length=2)
player = models.CharField(max_length=50)
position = models.CharField(max_length=2)
height = models.CharField(max_length=50)
weight = models.CharField(max_length=50)
birth = models.DateField()
exp = models.CharField(max_length=50)
college = models.CharField(max_length=50)

def __str__(self):
    return self.player
```

I have a list of over 500 players with these data associated, and I've also been able to create a JSON string that reads as:

```
[
 {"number": playernumber,
  "player": playername,
  "position": playerposition,
  "height":playerheight,
  "weight": playerweight,
  "birth":playerbirthdate
  "exp": playerexperience
  "college": playercollege
  }
]
```

I believe that the documentation has changed recently to promote the use of data migrations, but I'm a bit unclear on whether that is to change the fields of the data or to actually enter bits of data into this.  Also, the JSON string might change from time-to-time (either adding records or editing fields) so I'd like to have a bit of flexibility with how this data gets entered into the database.

I am also open to entering this data through a view, but I'm not sure on how to execute that view to get the data into the database.

I hope that I have made my issue clear.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest two options:

1. Through the view. Eventually you create a `FormView` with a form to upload a file or just a textbox and handle the json on backend.
2. You may create a manage.py command that receives path to a file as a parameter.

In both cases handling of your json will look like follows regardless of where you put it:

```
json_objects = json.loads(raw_json)
objects = []
for json_obj in json_objects:
    objects.append(Player(** json_obj))
Player.objects.bulk_create(objects)
```

You may delete all players with `Player.objects.all().delete()` before executing `bulk_create` in case you are need to refresh all players. Alternatively, you have an option to use [update_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) method to update existing objects while creating new ones.

Comment: Thanks Andrey.  In your code `(raw_json)` is the file or a string variable?

Comment: By `raw_json` I mean the string that represents your json. If you are operating with file you should probably do `open('path/to/file', 'r').read()` first.

Comment: Got it.  This is great.  Let's say I go with option #2 how do I execute the manage.py command?  Through the shell?  or does it just magically happen?

Comment: Magic is quite unlikely case :) Depending on how you configure it the name can change but eventually it would be `python manage.py load_players /path/to/file.json`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/

Another option is to use standard `python manage.py loaddata` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-loaddata) but it has limited features so make sure you don't need extra things.

Comment: Thanks.  I started reading the 1.9 documentation about command lines after I sent that last question.  I will look into loaddata as well.  Thanks.

Comment: One last thing- how do I activate the script from views.py.  That code just kind of sits there and it works in idle with a print, but i'm not sure how to make it work in django.

Comment: manage.py commands aren't suppose to be running from views. if you want to run it by view - put that to the view